# How to get the count of a list inside a JPA query?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, jpql

I have to count all exists object using jpa query. So, I need the count of ids in set from my query.
Here is the Repository Code:

```java
public interface ProductRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Product, String>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Product> {

    @Query("SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(p.id) = COUNT ( :ids )THEN true ELSE false END " +
        "FROM Product p  WHERE p.id IN :ids")
    boolean existsProductsByIdIn(Set<String> ids);

}
```

in above code **COUNT ( :ids )** is not working.
I've also tried with **SIZE (:ids)**.

**Note:** I don't want to pass the size as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

The issue you're encountering is because JPA does not support direct count of collection parameters within the JPQL. Instead, you can use a native SQL query to achieve this. If you want to stick with JPQL, you'd need to pass the size as a separate parameter (which you mentioned you do not want).

However, there's a workaround with JPQL using `INDEX` function:

```java
public interface ProductRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Product, String>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Product> {

    @Query("SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(p) = (SELECT MAX(INDEX(id)) FROM Product p1 WHERE p1.id IN :ids) + 1 THEN true ELSE false END " +
           "FROM Product p WHERE p.id IN :ids")
    boolean existsProductsByIdIn(Set<String> ids);

}
```

With this approach, we're assuming the `:ids` set doesn't have gaps in its index. The `+ 1` is because `INDEX` is 0-based. This solution should give you the desired results without the need for native SQL or passing the size separately.

Comment: the code is not correct. index expects a collection from entity. I've tried with index(p) rather than index(id), still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you thing this might give you the same result?

```
COUNT(p.id) = COUNT(DISTINCT p.id )
```

You are comparing input SET of values, which are just the distinct values in your query. If you will compare the total id with distinct id,  you might get the desired result.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(p.id) = COUNT(DISTINCT p.id ) THEN true ELSE false END " +
            "FROM Test p  WHERE p.id IN :ids
```

Comment: it is not working. you will get only those products from DB which exist in the database.
`COUNT(p.id) = COUNT(DISTINCT p.id )` this statement is always true. it won't consider the ids which are not present